# Zip a git repository directory with `.git` directory included

Tags: git, zip, gzip, tar

I am trying to zip a git repository directory with the `.git` directory included. I tried doing a tar on the directory, but it creates a bigger folder than original because it appends all the submodules.

I have tried the following commands but they zip without the `.git` directory-

`git archive master --format=tar --output="../gridImageSearch.zip"`

The following commands zips with `.git` directory, but the folder is too big -

`tar -zcvf ../blah.tar.gz blah`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Compress the git repository using

```
tar -c -f - foo | gzip >foo.tgz
```

If you wish to compress the repository without `.git` directory then run

```
tar -c --exclude .git -f - foo | gzip >foo.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

If your git repository directory contains files that are not versioned and you don't want to include them in the zip file, a simpler alternative is to `git clone` the repository to a new directory, and compress the whole new directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible answer.  You can use the `find` command to generate a list of all the files in your repository, exluding those contained in submodules.  We identify a submodule as "a directory that contains a `.git` directory".  The find command would be:

```
find . \( \! -depth 0 -type d -execdir test -f {}/.git \; -prune \) \
  -o -type f -print
```

That means "looking at everything contained in this directory, if it is a directory and contains a directory named `.git` *and* is not the top-level directory, do not descend into it, otherwise print out the filename".

You can use this as input into the `tar` command:

```
tar -T- -n -cz -f repo.tar.gz
```

That accepts a list of files on stdin (`-T-`, makes sure do not recurse into subdirectories (because `find` has done that for us), and creates (`-c`) gzip-compressed (`-z`) output.

The full command looks like:

```
find . \( \! -depth 0 -type d -execdir test -f {}/.git \; -prune \) \
  -o -type f -print |
tar -T- -n -cz -f repo.tar.gz
```

This would create a compress tar archive named `repo.tar.gz` in your current directory.

Ways that this will fail:

- By not using `git archive`, you may in accidentally includes files in your working directory that are not part of the git repository.  Using `git clean` can help avoid that.
- You may also build an archive that includes changes that have not yet been committed to the repository.  You can avoid this by explicitly checking for uncomitted changes before running your script.